# Python pandas for reading in file with date

Tags: python, pandas

In the dataframe below, the 3rd line is the header and the Y, M and D columns are giving year month and day respectively. However, I am not able to read them in using this code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(file_name, skiprows = 2, index_col='datetime', 
                 parse_dates={'datetime': [0,1,2]}, 
                 date_parser=lambda x: pandas.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d'))
```

---

```
         OTH-000.opc
              XKN1=    0.500000E-01
    Y   M   D     PRCP     VWC1    
 2006   1   1      0.0  0.17608E+00
 2006   1   2      6.0  0.21377E+00
 2006   1   3      0.1  0.22291E+00
 2006   1   4      3.0  0.23460E+00
 2006   1   5      6.7  0.26076E+00
```

I get a KeyError: List index out of range. Any suggestions?

Comment: This sample data works for me.  Perhaps there is an issue with the data?  Have you tested it to ensure that it is valid?

Comment: yes, i am using this exact same data

Comment: Which version of python and Pandas?

Comment: python 2.7, pandas: 0.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default separator in `read_csv` is a comma.  Your file doesn't use commas as separators, so you're only getting one big column:

```
>>> pd.read_csv(file_name, skiprows = 2)
       Y   M   D     PRCP     VWC1    
0   2006   1   1      0.0  0.17608E+00
1   2006   1   2      6.0  0.21377E+00
2   2006   1   3      0.1  0.22291E+00
3   2006   1   4      3.0  0.23460E+00
4   2006   1   5      6.7  0.26076E+00
>>> pd.read_csv(file_name, skiprows = 2).columns
Index([u'    Y   M   D     PRCP     VWC1    '], dtype='object')
```

You should be able to use `delim_whitespace=True`:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv(file_name, skiprows = 2, delim_whitespace=True,
                     parse_dates={"datetime": [0,1,2]}, index_col="datetime")
>>> df
            PRCP     VWC1
datetime                 
2006-01-01   0.0  0.17608
2006-01-02   6.0  0.21377
2006-01-03   0.1  0.22291
2006-01-04   3.0  0.23460
2006-01-05   6.7  0.26076
>>> df.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2006-01-01, ..., 2006-01-05]
Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

(I didn't specify the `date_parser`, because I'm lazy and this would be read correctly by default, but it's actually not a bad habit to be explicit.)

Comment: thanks! delim_whitespace helps, however, when I do df.index, I do not get a time series. any idea why?

Comment: follow up question for the query above is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805372/date-parse-error-in-python-pandas-while-reading-file