# Date parse error in Python pandas while reading file

Tags: python, pandas

Follow on question to: [Python pandas for reading in file with date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804236/python-pandas-for-reading-in-file-with-date/29805004#29805004)

I am not able to parse the date on the dataframe below. The code is as follows:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(file_name, skiprows = 2, index_col='datetime', 
                 parse_dates={'datetime': [0,1,2]}, delim_whitespace=True,
                 date_parser=lambda x: pandas.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d'))
```

---

```
         OTH-000.opc
              XKN1=    0.500000E-01
    Y   M   D     PRCP     VWC1    
 2006   1   1      0.0  0.17608E+00
 2006   1   2      6.0  0.21377E+00
 2006   1   3      0.1  0.22291E+00
 2006   1   4      3.0  0.23460E+00
 2006   1   5      6.7  0.26076E+00
```

I get an error saying: lambda () takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Based on @EdChum's comment below, if I use this code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(file_name, skiprows = 2, index_col='datetime', parse_dates={'datetime': [0,1,2]}, delim_whitespace=True))
```

df.index results in an object and not a datetime series

```
df.index
Index([u'2006 1 1',u'2006 1 2'....,u'nan nan nan'],dtype='object')
```

Finally the file is available here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xgk2w4ed9mi4lx/test.txt?dl=0

Comment: Does this work: `df = pandas.read_csv(file_name, skiprows = 2, index_col='datetime', 
                 parse_dates={'datetime': [0,1,2]}, delim_whitespace=True))` as this works for me, it seems the pandas parser is man/woman enough to handle your date format

Comment: If I do that, then df.index results in an object and not a time series.

Comment: This definitely works for me though using pandas 0.16.0 and numpy 1.9.1 python 3.4.3 64-bit, what version pandas, numpy and python are you using?

Comment: Regarding the incorrect index dtype could you try `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` this shouldn't be necessary but it should work for you

Comment: hmm, index still remains an object after df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index). My python is 2.7 (32 bit), pandas 0.16 and numpy 1.9.2

Comment: Could you edit into your post what your df.index now looks like thanks

Comment: thanks, post updated with index

Comment: There must be something else weird with your file which copying and pasting doesn't show here, are you able to post a link to the first few lines of the file, thanks

Comment: thanks! here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xgk2w4ed9mi4lx/test.txt?dl=0  Also updated question with this link

Comment: You seem to have an additional blank line at the end of your file, this is screwing the parser and introducing blank spaces for your dates, can you try removing any empty blank lines at the end of the file as it now parses fine for me

Comment: thanks! that's right, plz make this an answer so I can accept. Surprised though that blank lines are causing pandas grief.

Comment: Glad I could help, once you rule out software versions you have to then suspect the file has something funny about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I see the problem, your file had extraneous blank lines at the end, unfortunately this messes up the parser as it's looking for whitespace, this caused the df to look the following:

```
Out[25]:
             PRCP     VWC1
datetime                  
2006 1 1      0.0  0.17608
2006 1 2      6.0  0.21377
2006 1 3      0.1  0.22291
2006 1 4      3.0  0.23460
2006 1 5      6.7  0.26076
nan nan nan   NaN      NaN
```

When I remove the blank lines it imports and parses the dates fine:

```
Out[26]:
            PRCP     VWC1
datetime                 
2006-01-01   0.0  0.17608
2006-01-02   6.0  0.21377
2006-01-03   0.1  0.22291
2006-01-04   3.0  0.23460
2006-01-05   6.7  0.26076
```

and the index is now a datetimeindex as desired:

```
In [27]:

df.index
Out[27]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2006-01-01, ..., 2006-01-05]
Length: 5, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```