# NotImplementedError: file structure not yet supported from pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I get a `NotImplementedError: file structure not yet supported`when I run the code below on this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nh117yurq6rk2g7/300113R1.DNC?dl=0)

```
import constants, pandas, pdb
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df = pandas.read_csv('300113R1.DNC', skiprows = 11, delim_whitespace=True,usecols=['Y','M','D','PRCP'],
                     parse_dates={"datetime": [0,1,2]}, index_col="datetime",
                    date_parser=lambda x: pandas.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d'))
```

Any idea on what might be going wrong? Related query on a smaller sample of this same dataset is here:
[Date parse error in Python pandas while reading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805372/date-parse-error-in-python-pandas-while-reading-file?noredirect=1#comment47739746_29805372)

Comment: You have missing column headers, the last valid header is `SMES21` so you could either pass `header=None` or look at how this file was generated and fix the missing headers

Comment: thanks, i would be happy to accept this as answer.

Comment: I've posted a method that worked for me, it does mean renaming the '3' column but I've included this also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @cosmoscalibur for spotting that your file is missing columns, one solution is to skip parsing the header:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('300113R1.DNC', skiprows = 12, delim_whitespace=True,usecols=[0,1,2,3], header=None
                     parse_dates={"datetime": [0,1,2]}, index_col="datetime",
                    date_parser=lambda x: pandas.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d'))
```

this will require you to rename the single column from '3' to 'PRCP' after loading:

```
df = df.rename(columns={3:'PRCP'})
```

Answer (score 1):

> NotImplementedError

is when the method is not implemented. Name reference of the method exists but not the code inside of method. This is very useful to say that in the future this method will be part of the library.

Comment: thanks, I do get that, it seems like this file should be readable though.

Comment: I agree with the OP, I can't see anything particularly special with this file it should be readable

Comment: What Panda version do you use? @user308827

Comment: thanks @EdChum, I think I can see the reason why. There are some columns at the very end of the file which have no headers. When I remove those columns, the file gets read fine. So the question is how to exclude those columns!

Comment: @cosmoscalibur, pandas version 0.16

Comment: yes well spotted, you could just skip the header and name them after, otherwise I would look at how this file was generated and fix the missing column headers

Comment: thanks, latter is not an option, but the former idea makes sense.