# Reading no-header CSV to pandas dataframe and parsing date

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read similar to below CSV file to pandas.DataFrame:

```
2011    1   10  AAPL    Buy     1500
2011    1   13  AAPL    Sell    1500
2011    1   13  IBM     Buy     4000
2011    1   26  GOOG    Buy     1000
```

Data doesn't have column headers. When I read that file I also want to parse first 3 columns to a 'date' column. So the following is what I tried:

```
import pandas
pandas.read_csv(fileName,
                header = None,
                names = ('Date', 'Symbol', 'Side', 'Quantity'),
                parse_dates = {'Date' : [0, 1, 2]})
```

That raises:

```
NotImplementedError: file structure not yet supported
```

I tried:

```
pandas.read_csv(fileName,
                header = None,
                names = ('Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Symbol', 'Side', 'Quantity'),
                parse_dates = {'Date' : ['Year', 'Month', 'Day']})
```

and neither did that work and threw the same exception.

So finally I accomplished reading that file by:

```
orders = pandas.read_csv(fileName,
                         header = None,
                         parse_dates = {'Date' : [0, 1, 2]})
orders.rename(columns = {3: 'Symbol', 4 : 'Side', 5: 'Quantity'})
```

Is there a way to make the first call to work by passing column names to names? Why that exception is raised?
Similar problem was reported in [Pandas file structure not supported error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29806330/pandas-file-structure-not-supported-error) but I couldn't see any solution other than the same workaround.

I am using pandas 0.18.1 which is the latest version to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add:

```
sep='\s+'
```

or

```
delim_whitespace=True
```

parameter

Demo:

```
In [7]: %paste
(pd.read_csv(fileName, sep='\s+', header = None,
             names = ('Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Symbol', 'Side', 'Quantity'),
             parse_dates = {'Date' : ['Year', 'Month', 'Day']})
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[7]:
        Date Symbol  Side  Quantity
0 2011-01-10   AAPL   Buy      1500
1 2011-01-13   AAPL  Sell      1500
2 2011-01-13    IBM   Buy      4000
3 2011-01-26   GOOG   Buy      1000

In [8]: %paste
(pd.read_csv(fileName, delim_whitespace=True, header = None,
             names = ('Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Symbol', 'Side', 'Quantity'),
             parse_dates = {'Date' : ['Year', 'Month', 'Day']})
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[8]:
        Date Symbol  Side  Quantity
0 2011-01-10   AAPL   Buy      1500
1 2011-01-13   AAPL  Sell      1500
2 2011-01-13    IBM   Buy      4000
3 2011-01-26   GOOG   Buy      1000
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxU. The actual structure of the file is:

`2011,1,10,AAPL,Buy,1500,  
2011,1,13,AAPL,Sell,1500,  
2011,1,13,IBM,Buy,4000,  
2011,1,26,GOOG,Buy,1000,`  
So eventually I added dummy column   `names = ('Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Symbol', 'Side', 'Quantity', 'bla'),`   because of the comma and it worked. The exception can be a bit clearer though..